# Salesforce - Record-trigerred flow - Comparing fields value between two custom objects (master-detail relationship)

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm a beginner at Salesforce and I'm encountering the following issue: I have created two custom objects, Job Position (master) and Job Application (child). Both customs objects have 3 fields with the same value set that I want to compare between each other.

I'm trying to create a record-triggered flow starting on the job application (created or updated), to check if there's no match between the fields value, and send an automatic mail in that case, but no matter the combination I'm using in the Flow Builder, nothing seems to work out. I started from a rather straight-forward flow as seen on the picture but now, I'm going deeper the rabbit hole with patterns that I'm pretty sure shouldn't be as complicated.

I've tried several patterns: starting on the job application (record triggered flow), get records from Job position, adding a decision checking the fields with 'does not equal operator', throwing in a loop, and so in every possible order. Yet I can't seem to find the right way to set up my flow.

Either I'm retrieving empty fields values (which should not be possible since all test records are filled), or I'm retrieving the values for only one specific job position instead of the job position linked to the job application (in the case of using a loop).

EDIT: When I use get records on Job Position and then use a decision, the fields values I want to use in the outcome are null (discovered from debugging). I've tried saving the values in an assignment but my variables are not recognised.

EDIT2: my get record is filtered not to get null data

If anyone has an idea on how to set it, or could guide me, please let me know, thank you!